# Can OS processes share a single CPU stack?

Tags: operating-system, cpu, cpu-architecture

Can processes share a single stack?

I'm currently thinking yes and no. That they "share" stack but it need to copy and save the information already there elsewere before using it and return it when the first process is getting picked up by the CPU again. But I might be confusing this with registers in general. 
Can someone help me shed some light on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Processes do not share CPU stacks.

While processes can potentially share memory using shared-memory facilities, processes do not share memory by default. Operating systems try to minimize the amount of sharing between processes as a way to ensure security.

Sharing CPU stack between processes A and B would be detrimental to security, because process A would be able to poke around "junk" left on the stack by process B, and vice versa. Hackers managed to exploit an indirect sharing on a much smaller scale to create a major security vulnerability (you can read more about [*Meltdown* and *Spectre* here](https://meltdownattack.com/)). Sharing CPU stacks would create a much bigger problem.

It goes without saying that an attempt to share stacks would require a degree of inter-process synchronization that would be prohibitive to overall performance. An ability to make independent operations on CPU stack is so critical to concurrency that threads inside the same process are allocated separate stacks, even though they already share all the memory allocated to the process, so security is not a concern. Sharing stacks would effectively kill concurrency, because maintaining a shared stack would require frequent exclusive access with lots of synchronization.

Comment: Well, different threads do not share stack not because of performance, but because you want them to be able to progress independently where each may call its own functions and need its own stack. This is however not related to security and the threads will probably share pointers to some global stack for variables defined there prior to their spawning.

Answer (score 0):

Some systems use an interrupt stack shared by all processes. Generally, there is one interrupt stack per processor.

User stacks (and there is usually one for each processor mode used by the system) are unique to each process (or thread).

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the registers and the stack is that the latter can be anywhere in memory (it is indirectly referenced by appropriate registers) while the formers are fixed (there is only one set of architecturally visible registers).

The stack is part of the state of a program, just like it make no sense to mix program instruction, data and context together, mixing two stacks make no sense.
If program A pushes X it expects to pop X and not an eventual value pushed by program B meanwhile.

It's possible to make all program shares the same memory area for the stack but this is, in general, counterproductive.
As you correctly noted, the stack must be swapped in an out, thus, in the case of two program A and B, two additional memory areas are needed: one for saving the stack of A and one for the stack of B.
In the end, three memory areas are used instead of two.

There are cases where the swapping is necessary: when the shared is at a fixed location.
This is the case, in some degenerate form, of registers but other structure can have a fixed location.
One simple example are the [page table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table) entries, if a program A is used to generate two processes A1 and A2, most OSs will [copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) them.
Under this circumstances, the two processes end up sharing a lot of pages, even all but a few. For the OS may be easier to swap in and out the few different pages rather than make the page table (or part of it) point to two different locations.

In general, if we cannot afford to have multiple instances of a resource, we need to time-share it.
Since we can afford to have more than one instance of the stack, we prefer to not share it.